# how to read data from remote mongo database server by using shell script via ssh connection

Tags: mongodb, ssh

I would like to read data from remote mongo database server. I tried by below ways.

ssh username@hostname 
"mongo databaseName --eval 'db.collection.find({\"params1\":\"2\",\"params2\":\"2\"})'"

or

ssh username@hostname
"mongo databaseName --eval 'printjson(db.collection.find({\"params1\":\"2\", \"params2\":\"2\"}))'"

I used both ways, but I can't get the correct result output from database server.
How should I do ?

Answer (score 6):

The following format should work, note that I specifically included the full path of the mongo executable on the remote database server. If this command does not work, you should ensure that SSH is running on the server and check to see if there is any authentication settings on your database.

```
ssh username@hostname "/usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongo --norc --eval 'db.collection.find().forEach(printjson)'"
```

Comment: Connection is OK but I don't get the result output.              MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0
connecting to: test
DBQuery: test.groups -> undefined

Comment: If you want to capture the output using a script (I'll use bash to illustrate) you will need to use a variable and you will also need to redirect the standard error (stderr) to the standard output (stdout) to get the result you want: result=$(ssh username@hostname "/usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongo --norc --eval 'db.collection.find().forEach(printjson)'" 2>&1)